# MongoDB Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that's structured as follows:

```
{
  '_id' => 'Star Wars',
  'count' => 1234,
  'spelling' => [ ( 'Star wars' => 10, 'Star Wars' => 15, 'sTaR WaRs' => 5) ]
}
```

I would like to get the top N documents (by descending count), but with only one one spelling per document (the one with the highest value). It there a way to do this with the aggregation framework?

I can easily get the top 10 results (using $sort and $limit). But how do I get only one spelling per each?

So for example, if I have the following three records:

```
{
  '_id' => 'star_wars',
  'count' => 1234,
  'spelling' => [ ( 'Star wars' => 10, 'Star Wars' => 15, 'sTaR WaRs' => 5) ]
}
{
  '_id' => 'willow',
  'count' => 2211,
  'spelling' => [ ( 'willow' => 300, 'Willow' => 550) ]
}
{
  '_id' => 'indiana_jones',
  'count' => 12,
  'spelling' => [ ( 'indiana Jones' => 10, 'Indiana Jones' => 25, 'indiana jones' => 5) ]
}
```

And I ask for the top 2 results, I'll get:

```
{
  '_id' => 'willow',
  'count' => 2211,
  'spelling' => 'Willow'
}
{
  '_id' => 'star_wars',
  'count' => 1234,
  'spelling' => 'Star Wars'
}
```

(or something to this effect)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema as designed would make using anything but a MapReduce difficult as you've used the keys of the object as values. So, I adjusted your schema to better match with MongoDB's capabilities (in JSON format as well for this example):

```
{
  '_id' : 'star_wars',
  'count' : 1234,
  'spellings' : [ 
    { spelling: 'Star wars', total: 10}, 
    { spelling: 'Star Wars', total : 15}, 
    { spelling: 'sTaR WaRs', total : 5} ]
}
```

Note that it's now an array of objects with a specific key name, `spelling`, and a value for the `total` (I didn't know what that number actually represented, so I've called it total in my examples).

On to the aggregation:

```
db.so.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$spellings' }, 
    { $project: { 
        'spelling' : '$spellings.spelling', 
        'total': '$spellings.total', 
        'count': '$count'  
        }
    }, 
    { $sort : { total : -1 } }, 
    { $group : { _id : '$_id',
        count: { $first: '$count' },
        largest : { $first : '$total' },
        spelling : { $first: '$spelling' }
        }
    }
])
```

1. Unwind all of the data so the aggregation pipeline can access the various values of the array
2. Flatten the data to include the key aspects needed by the pipeline. In this case, the specific `spelling`, the `total`, and the `count`.
3. Sort on the `total`, so that the last grouping can use `$first`
4. Then, group so that only the `$first` value for each `_id` is returned, and then also return the `count` which because of the way it was flattened for the pipeline, each temporary document will contain the `count` field.

Results:

```
[
{
    "_id" : "star_wars",
    "count" : 1234,
    "largest" : 15,
    "spelling" : "Star Wars"
},
{
    "_id" : "indiana_jones",
    "count" : 12,
    "largest" : 25,
    "spelling" : "Indiana Jones"
},
{
    "_id" : "willow",
    "count" : 2211,
    "largest" : 550,
    "spelling" : "Willow"
}
]
```

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie. Appreciated. Was considering changing the schema (as you suggested). The problem I have is that I'm not sure, or just don't know how to, update the new schema in the following case:

How would I (in the new schema) update a record to increase its count by 1, and to increase the count of one of the spellings by 1, in the same update statement? (so, to increase 'count' by 1, and to increase 'total' for one of the spellings by one)

Comment: I'd recommend using the shell and just writing a simple script that loops through the documents of your collection and updates the schema one doc at a time.

Comment: I would have preferred you accept/vote on this question and start a second question ... :)

Comment: Like this: `db.movies.update( {_id: "star_wars", 'spellings.spelling' : "Star wars" }, { $inc : { 'spellings.$.total' : 1, 'count' : 1 }})`

Comment: I created a quick blog post to match the $inc issue: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1895

Comment: Thanks again. Would vote as soon as I have enough reputation to vote! (as I just registered I still need a few more reputation points before it would allow me). I do have a follow-up question on your solution, and will open it up as a new thread as per your request :)

Comment: And here is the follow-up question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641531/mongodb-upserting-and-sub-documents

Comment: (You should be able to accept the answer if this is correct).