# MongoDB: Upserting and Sub documents

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume the following schema:

```
{
  '_id' : 'star_wars',
  'count' : 1234,
  'spellings' : [ 
    { spelling: 'Star wars', total: 10}, 
    { spelling: 'Star Wars', total : 15}, 
    { spelling: 'sTaR WaRs', total : 5} ]
}
```

I can update the count and one of the spellings by doing this:

```
db.movies.update( 
    {_id: "star_wars",
     'spellings.spelling' : "Star Wars" },
    { $inc : 
        { 'spellings.$.total' : 1, 
        'count' : 1 }}
)
```

But this form of update doesn't work with upsert. i.e., if I try to update (with upsert) with an _id that doesn't exist, or with a spelling that doesn't already exist, nothing happens.

Is there a solution that allows me to upsert when updating ($inc) a sub-document?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the query with the `upsert` that doesn't work so we can help you. If you use the above query with the `upsert` option there is no `new spelling` defined, so eventually it will not add any. It will just update the existing spellings

Comment: I have tried the above query, with the upsert option. Is there another way to write it? I basically want to update 'count', and 'total' for a specific spelling (with +1 each), but with upsert (i.e. that a whole document will be created if _id isn't matched, or a sub-document will be created if _id is matched but the specific spelling isn't there).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upsert Array Elements matching criteria in a MongoDB document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871363/upsert-array-elements-matching-criteria-in-a-mongodb-document)

Comment: Fair enough. Sounds like it's not possible in a single update. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your schema a little, though. If your documents looked like this:

```
{
  '_id' : 'star_wars',
  'count' : 1234,
  'spellings' :  
    { 
        'Star wars': 10, 
        'Star Wars': 15, 
        'sTaR WaRs': 5
    }
}
```

Your updates would become as simple as:

```
db.movies.update({_id:"star_wars"},{$inc:{"spellings.Star Wars":1}},true)
```

Comment: Stefan, that's where I originally started, but then I have this problem instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639651/mongodb-aggregation-framework :)

Comment: I see. I don't think there's a solution that would solve both of your problems :(