# How to update sub documents value of different documents based on different filter in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

How to update sub documents value of different documents based on different filter in mongoDB with a single script

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa2516c732e89b875rtg"),
"username" : "user1",
"password" : "password1",
"level0" : {
    "level1" : {
        "value1" : 2,
        "value2" : 2
     }
   }
 },
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa2516c732e89b8hy5"),
  "username" : "user2",
  "password" : "password2",
  "level0" : {
    "level1" : {
        "differntvalue1" : 2,
        "differntvalue2" : 2
     }
   }
 }
```

here i just want to update the documents(with newly added values in sub documents) by running a single script and result should be like below

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa2516c732e89b875rtg"),
  "username" : "user1",
  "password" : "password1",
   "level0" : {
    "level1" : {
       "value1" : 2,
       "value2" : 2,
       "value3" : 2
   }
 }
},
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa2516c732e89b8hy5"),
   "username" : "user2",
   "password" : "password2",
   "level0" : {
     "level1" : {
        "differntvalue1" : 2,
        "differntvalue2" : 2,
        "differntvalue3" : 2
   }
 }
}
```

[MongoDB: Upserting and Sub documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641531/mongodb-upserting-and-sub-documents) -this answer is helpful but not allowing different updates on different docs at same time.

Comment: did you try using parent.$.child?

Comment: yes.this is already tried and for single document update it is working fine.but not for multiple docs.why $ symbol is not accepting,i tried as parent.child and which works

Comment: Can you show the current code ? What are different filters ? What is the search criteria ?

Comment: @Veeram -please find the below answer for my current code and let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: don't think it is possible. you just need to do two queries. you can only update multiple documents with same values for different filter in one query.

Comment: not just two,i have to update multiple documents as such.Yes,you are right. **multi=true**  or **updateMany()** will update multiple docs with same value only.

Comment: how about bulk writes ?

Answer (score 0):

I Just tried it with different update commands for each document.is there a way to do it together with a single update?

```
 db.mycollection.update(
   {"username": "user1"},
   { 
   $set :{
     "level0.level1.value3" : 2
     }
    });
 db.mycollection.update(
  {"username": "user2"},
  { 
   $set :{
    "level0.level1.differntvalue3" : 2
    }
  });
```